# How can I insert into one table and update another table with the same sql statement?

Tags: sql

The requirement to do it in one statement is because of how the program handles sql statements.  The sql statement is stored in a column of another table, and executed through an open on a recordset.  The open responds with an error of invalid character if a semi-colon is in the statement.

The scenario: Under certain conditions, I want to update a particular field in one record in database A, and record the fact of that change in a log table by an insert.

Here's an example using two statements:

```
update data_table a set field1='new value' where identifier=10;

insert into log_table (action_taken) 
values('record ' || a.identifier || ' had field1 changed to ' || a.field1);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could add the second statement as a trigger...

Comment: You can't do it in a single sql statement.  Your options are the trigger suggested by meager or the stored procedure suggested by krefftc.

Answer (score 3):

Put them both in a stored procedure and execute call the stored procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not want to log it unless the change is made by a certain procedure.  A trigger would log it on every change.  I have not used stored procedures before, are they easy to learn?  BTW, I'm using Oracle under VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for TRIGGERS. Without knowing what database you are using I can only guess.

Here is information about triggers for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

A trigger is tied to a table to start on a specific event, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. The trigger can then run one or more SQL statements.

And here is how you create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make a batch call to the SGDB you can do what you have done, if you are using java or .net both of the their SQL API support sql batch commands.

```
update data_table a set field1='new value' where identifier=10;
GO
insert into log_table (action_taken) 
values('record ' || a.identifier || ' had field1 changed to ' || a.field1);
GO
```

But if you are going to do this two operations at the same time all the time you should accept krefftc answer because it's the best way

Answer (score 0):

If your database happens to be Oracle you may be able to use an anonymous PL/SQL block if for some reason you can't/don't want to create a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
 update data_table a set field1='new value' where identifier=10;

 insert into log_table (action_taken) 
  values('record ' || a.identifier || ' had field1 changed to ' || a.field1);
END;
```

Comment: I did actually try this in Oracle, but kept getting invalid character whenever I included a semi-colon.  If you know a way around that, it might solve my problem.

Comment: You won't if you use the `BEGIN` and `END` constructs as I've suggested. That should work